# how to properly create and import node modules in typescript

Tags: node.js, module, typescript

How do I create node modules in typescript to be imported in other typescript files? I have searched and searched but cannot find how to do this properly.

I want to create a typescript module that exports some functions that I can import using require into my app.ts. I am using 'typescript-require'. Here is what I am doing (simplified):

### app.ts

```
require('typescript-require');
import config = require('./config');

console.log(config.GetDefaultConfiguration());
```

### config.ts

```
module config {
    var defaultConfig = "default configuration";
    export function GetDefaultConfiguration() {
        return defaultConfig;
    }
}
```

### config.d.ts

```
declare module config {

}
```

But I get "TypeError: Object # has no method 'GetDefaultConfiguration'".

What am I missing?

Comment: I know this is a pretty old question, but for anyone else stumbling across it (as I did this past week), you might find this typescript boilerplate project helpful: https://github.com/bitjson/typescript-starter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using 'typescript-require'

Don't use it. Just compile to JS from TSC and then run the JS.

> I get "TypeError: Object # has no method 'GetDefaultConfiguration'".

You need to `export` from `config.ts`:

```
var defaultConfig = "default configuration";
export function GetDefaultConfiguration() {
     return defaultConfig;
}
```

Note: don't use *internal modules* with *external modules*. If you are unclear about the difference. Watch this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: Thanks Basarat. Sounds weird but I tried that earlier and got compile errors. I am building my application in VS2013 using the node.js tools for Visual Studio and the build system has been pretty erratic. I did a clean build and with your suggested changes its working now.

Comment: I use grunt https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts simply because the Visual Studio compile pipeline for TypeScript is suboptimal. Note that the TypeScript team itself uses jake (not msbuild) to manage its compile

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will take a look at grunt and jake.