# How to Properly Export and Import Modules in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

***Note:*** *I know there are many posts on this topic, and I've reviewed quite a few already without success (please see my references at the bottom of this post).*

I'm trying to run a very simple test in TypeScript, using Visual Studio Code, where I declare a class in one file and import it into another file. However, I continue to run into an issue where the file I am importing into is not recognizing the methods of the class that I exported from the other file.

The exact error messages that I'm receiving at this point are:

> [ts] Property 'getFirstName' does not exist on type 'typeof "module-test/src/OtherClass"'.
>
> [ts] Property 'getLastName' does not exist on type 'typeof "module-test/src/OtherClass"'.

I'm using Node 9.3.0 and TypeScript 2.6.2.

Many thanks in advance for any guidance that anyone can offer me!

**main.ts**

```js
import * as Other from "./OtherClass";

class myApp
{
  public async start()
  {
    console.log("Starting application");
    
    try
    {
      let firstName = await Other.getFirstName();
      console.log("First Name: " + firstName);
      let lastName = await Other.getLastName();
      console.log("Last Name: " + lastName);
    }
    catch (error)
    {
      console.error("Unable to get name: " + error)
    }
    
    console.log("Ending application");
  }
}

const app = new myApp();
app.start();
```

**OtherClass.ts**

```js
class Other
{
  getFirstName(): string
  {
    return "John";
  }

  getLastName(): string
  {
    return "Doe";
  }
}

export { Other };
```

**Things I've Tried**

1. Exporting via the declaration

```js
export class Other
{
  getFirstName(): string
  {
    return "John";
  }

  getLastName(): string
  {
    return "Doe";
  }
}
```

2. Exporting the individual functions

```js
class Other
{
  export function getFirstName(): string
  {
    return "John";
  }

  export function getLastName(): string
  {
    return "Doe";
  }
}
```

3. Multiple export statements

```js
module.exports = Other;
export { Other };
export * from "OtherClass";
```

4. Multiple import statements

```js
import * as Other from "./OtherClass";
import { Other } from "./OtherClass";
```

**Configuration Files**
**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "module-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple test of exporting and importing modules",
  "main": "./lib/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "John Doe",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.5.2",
    "@types/typescript": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es2016",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "outDir": "./lib/",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": true,                            /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    "inlineSources": true                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */
  }
}
```

**Articles Referenced**

- [Property 'Server' does not exist on type 'typeof "http"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377686/property-server-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-http)
- [Node.js ES6 how to export class from module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395114/node-js-es6-how-to-export-class-from-module)
- [Difference between "module.exports" and "exports" in the CommonJs Module System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383795/difference-between-module-exports-and-exports-in-the-commonjs-module-system)
- [how to properly create and import node modules in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852111/how-to-properly-create-and-import-node-modules-in-typescript)
- [TypeScript - Export and import modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914303/typescript-export-and-import-modules)
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Where to begin? This is many edits away from a valid program; you should probably start with a working example as it's not 100% clear what you *want* this code to do.

You created a module with a single named export, the class `Other`.

```
export { Other };
```

You then imported the *surrounding module object*:

```
import * as Other from "./OtherClass";
```

In the importing file, the class now has the name `Other.Other`. But at no point in the code did you actually *instantiate* the class with `new`! So here

```
let firstName = await Other.getFirstName();
```

You need to write

```
const oth = new Other.Other();
```

This looks silly, of course. **Change** the import statement (don't have multiple!) to

```
import { Other } from "./OtherClass";
```

And now instead you can write

```
const oth = new Other();
```

Moving on, we write

```
let firstName = await oth.getFirstName();
```

Except that `getFirstName` isn't an async function, so you should really write

```
let firstName = oth.getFirstName();
```

Comment: Thanks @RyanCavanaugh! I totally spaced on instantiating the class in main.ts as you pointed out. Regarding the purpose of the code, it was merely meant to be a learning exercise on the proper importing of modules and referencing the imported code.