# I get "no exported member" when importing a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, export

I have a node/typescript application which I'm trying to import a function from another file. To export it I used `exports.coolFunc = coolFunc` and to import I used `import {coolFunc} from '../controller/coolStuff'`.

When I do that I get

> Module '"../controller/coolFunc"' has no exported member 'coolFunc'

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `Module '"../controller/coolFunc"' has no exported member 'coolFunc'`

^ This error indicates your import statement looks like

`import {coolFunc} from '../controller/coolFunc';`

when it should be

`import {coolFunc} from '../controller/coolStuff';`

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How to Properly Export and Import Modules in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028975/how-to-properly-export-and-import-modules-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

The import is an ES6 import. `exports.coolFunc = coolFunc` is wrong. It's a CommonJS export. The equivalent ES6 export is

```
export { coolFunc }
```

or

```
export function coolFunc...
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) you can read more about the syntax of ES6 `export`.

Comment: I have a couple functions I'm trying to export, so I tried `exports = {
    coolFunc: coolFunc,
    anotherOne: anotherOne,
}`
And it's still not working

Comment: @Jessica It's `export`, without `s` and without `=`.

Comment: Still not working. I'm now also getting errors saying `Cannot find name 'coolFunc'` in the export

Comment: @Jessica It seems like there are more bugs in your code. I can only solve the problems you've described in your question.

Comment: I'm just following what you said to do...

Comment: @Jessica That solved the problem in your question. Now you have a different problem I can't  help you with, because you didn't provide enough details.

Comment: Uh, it didn't...

Comment: @Jessica Your question contains `exports.coolFunc =`. That's not the correct syntax for ES6 `export`. I showed you correct syntax and gave you a link with more information. That's all the code you've provided. I can't fix code that I can't see. `Cannot find name 'coolFunc'` means that there is no such function in that module.